# Preview page 1 of pdf as image on React

Tags: reactjs, image, pdf.js

I'm trying to preview the first page of a pdf as an image in react. Most articles point to Pdf.js. I'm wondering if there are other alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try react-pdf-js or pdf-sample.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using react-pdf

I was able to limit the number of pages I could preview to one thus when was able to preview the first page of the pdf on upload.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf